# Need to display a form as a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have the following SINGLE JSON data object :

```
{
totSalesAmt : 123,
totSalesTillDate:1/1/20,
totVolumeAmt: 222,
totVolumeTillDate:2/2/20,
totVolumeBranch1Amt: 10,
totVolumeBranch1TillDate: 1/2/20,
totVolumeBranch1Pct: 14,
totVolumeBranch2Amt: 20,
totVolumeBranch2TillDate: 2/1/20,
totVolumeBranch2Pct: 22
}
```

But i would like to display it in a editable grid format , like this :

[image: Grid]

The user could click on any of the amt , till date and pct cells and update the data.

Which ext js 4.2.2 component is best suited for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DataView](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.view.View) to create grid.

In the Data View, you can style your css and html to custom your grid with [Ext.XTemplate](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate).

Comment: I looked at it. But that would mean i dont get a grid by default. I would have to create the headers, broder lines etc by css. Is that the only option ?